# How can I stream audio from my phone over wifi to a speaker or receiver?

Tags: wi-fi, audio, streaming

I have a Galaxy Nexus and would like to be able to send music from it to speakers or a receiver.

Since I use a few different apps to listen to music (Spotify and Pandora mostly but sometimes also Audible) I don't want to have to use a specific player.

And I'd like to do it all over WiFi because Bluetooth doesn't provide enough range for me (I've tried, many different ways).

Is there a way to do this with android?

What I'm **not** looking for:

- A way to **stream to or from a PC**.
- Anything involving BlueTooth.
- A new music player app on android - I want to stream music from any app on my phone to a wireless receiver or speaker.
- Anything involving software running on a PC.

This should work when my PC is off. I should be able to pull out my phone, open spotify or pandora or audible or google listen or whatever and hear the output on any speaker in the house.

Comment: I think you should clarify that you don't want to stream to a PC at all.  You want a non-PC piece of hardware to receive the stream.

Comment: [Replace audio cable with wireless solution](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36242/replace-audio-cable-with-wireless-solution) may be relevant.

Comment: You would think in this modern day that it would be widely supported and easy enough to just press the menu, connect to wifi speaker. and play. Exactly like bluetooth but just over wifi

Answer (score 2):

You would need to get the speakers accessible over wireless somehow.

This does that: https://store.google.com/product/chromecast_audio

Alternatively, you could plug your android phone directly into your speakers and remotely control your android phone over wifi with a laptop/PC. May need to be rooted for this however.

Comment: I've got a Logitech squeezebox which comes close but there are features in the android version of spotify that aren't in the squeezebox plugin. Seems like something that should be doable. If I can stream all audio through Bluetooth why not over wifi?

Comment: yes it should be doable and it is possible, but would require a service like the one i mentioned. bluetooth differs in that it has the built in protocol that allows device to device audio transmission. wifi operates on a broader set of protocols not specific to media. of course media can be transfered over wifi but to stream it you need an interpretor.

Answer (score 2):

[Netgear WN3500RP](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN3500RP.aspx) is what I would recommend to anyone who is looking for this functionality. It is a Wi-Fi Range Extender...meaning it connects to your existing Wi-Fi router and basically extends the Wi-Fi coverage. The USP of this device is that it supports Airplay/[DLNA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FGTazXDOyY).
How to use it?

- Plugin your speakers to its 3.5mm audio input port.
- Get an app to stream music from your phone over Wi-Fi. Preferably [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en).

That's it. Enjoy streaming music wirelessly!
P.S. You can also stream videos to any TV with an HDMI port, using this device. You probably need an **Ethernet to HDMI cable** for this. I haven't tried this though.

Comment: Does IOS / Andriod not have build in support for streaming to an audio device?

Comment: 10 years after the question has been asked **Get an app to stream music from your phone over Wi-Fi. Preferably BubbleUPnP** still seems to be the perfect answer. The receiver could be any of the long-long list.

Answer (score 0):

AirPlay  provides this but your airport express device which will be connected to Speakers and yes you will be able to stream from phone. This is all apple solution - not sure if there is an Android app which allows doing that ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay) tells that there are experimental apps which do that.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Sonus WiFi receiver does these things - not cheap though.  They have a system that you have to plug-into your amplifier and it works over WiFi.

http://www.sonos.com/search/wireless_speakers?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=sonos-speakers&utm_campaign=branded-terms&gclid=CJ3J0MXJu7UCFULf4AodmVAALQ

Comment: sonos doesn't do this. It will stream music from your phone but the files have to be on the phone or a PC or NAS mediaserver. I want to stream from spotify and/or amazon mp3's cloud player. They try to do this with apps but the apps are never as powerful as the desktop version of the program.

Answer (score 0):

kaiser baas wifi music streamer seems to be able to do what you want along with the android app that comes with it.

I was looking for something similar and just ordered it myself.

http://www.orb.net.au/media-player/wifi-music-streamer

Answer (score -1):

Use a [HiFi-WiFi box](http://www.philips-shop.co.uk/store/catalog/home-audio/wireless-audio/digital-connectivity/productdetail/AW1000_10_GB_SHOPPUB/GB/en). Connect it to your HiFi (AuxIn), then (using your smartphone and app) view all available devices with music and all available devices with speakers.

It's simple, costs about £150, but it's worth it. It also works with all devices connected to a WiFi network.

Comment: doesn't do it. streams music files from the phone but doesn't handle streaming music services like spotify or amazon mp3.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not afraid to get your hands dirty with a little DIY, you may be able to [adapt this to your situation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bp26xFBwrJs).

You're basically connecting your phone (with WiFi) to a router, the router to speakers. The audio streams wirelessly with wifi and plays on any speakers that are hooked to the router (which is done with a cheap usb sound card).
enjoy!

Comment: And when that link no longer works will this answer still be useful?

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a similar solution and I just found the [AwoX StriimLINK](http://www.awox.com/EN/striimlink.html).

The video is in French but the description and specs are in English. This should work for my needs, and hopefully yours too.

Answer (score -1):

I found an application that can do the trick, it is called "AirAudio" but you have to root your phone and I am not to sure about this, if some one have tested please let me know

Comment: So what: this app "can do the trick", or you don't know? Maybe you can provide a link to it to check?

Answer (score -2):

Sony's Walkman player does the job. You can stream your audio to network PC

Comment: OP has already stated that stream to a PC is exactly what they're not looking for.