# Replace audio cable with wireless solution

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio

I want audio from my Nexus 7 to play through my amplifier (without replacing it). I think this would be possible with the iPad/AppleTV combo.

I don't want to be locked to a specific app that only plays certain files etc, but more like being able to select another Audio Out destination. Also, I'd rather not use Bluetooth, since it needs to compress the audio.

You could probably say I want [Miracast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast), but for audio.

Sorry, lots of demands. Is there a device/protocol to make this happen?

Comment: If you "rather not use Bluetooth", why did you tag your question `bluetooth-audio`? Would you accept Bluetooth based solutions, but *prefer* other solutions? Just to clearify for possible answerers.

Comment: @Izzy Even though I don't want it, it's related to the question. Also I'm open to be convinced to use BT audio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways you could do this.

1. Bluetooth audio adapter, like the [Antec BXR100](http://store.antec.com/Product/audio/bxr-100-whi/0-761345-73031-0.aspx).  These are generally used for headphones, but should be able to simply connect into your amp. 
   -Pros : Simple, cheap 
   -Cons : Bluetooth, limited range, [A2DP appears to have issues on Android 4.2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39633), possibly non-optimal audio quality
2. DLNA renderer (mini computer (raspberry pi ([Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/) maybe.  There's a [topic](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=5450) on the use of raspbmc as a DLAN renderer here on their forums.) or similar perhaps), specialized unit (Like the (discontinued, though still findable if you don't mind buying used) [Netgear MP100 series](http://support.netgear.com/product/MP101)), or maybe a cheap Android device) attached to your amp, getting your audio pushed from one of the [several DLNA server apps available for Android](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=DLNA%20server&c=apps).  This is essentially the same as Apple's Airplay system, only a different, more open standard which will work with more manufacturers' devices.
   -Pros : Almost as simple, will work anywhere you can get a wifi signal, possibly better audio quality than the bluetooth, could potentially be used to move video if you wanted to in the future if your chosen receiver has that capability.
   -Cons : More complex, possibly expensive, new audio-only DLNA renderers seem to be rare nowadays.

Comment: I was actually thinking that it would be cool if there was a solution using Rasp PI. :) But can DLNA really be used for this? I thought it was only possible to share files with it.

Comment: @Znarkus Moving media between devices like this is the entire purpose of DLNA.

Comment: So just to clarify, I can send audio from Spotify, Youtube etc through DLNA?

Comment: @Znarkus - Spotify - Not presently.  Support for DLNA is ["under consideration"](http://community.spotify.com/t5/ideas/v2/ideapage/blog-id/ideaexchange/article-id/377), but has been there for most of a year with no evident progress on it.  My guess is licensing agencies being jerks. Youtube is much easier.  [Twonky](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pv.twonkybeam) will do that for you.

Comment: I used sony's bluetooth adapter. The problem is range - bluetooth sucks beyond a few feet. If I got up and interposed my body between the transmitter and the receiver audio would drop.

Comment: also DLNA won't do it. AFAIK you can only stream from your local library. So I can't stream spotify over DLNA using the regular spotify client (which has more features than any of the plugins for DLNA out there).

Comment: I have a [similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29566/how-can-i-stream-audio-from-my-phone-over-wifi-to-a-speaker-or-receiver#comment48306_29566) btw