# Realtime Transfer (Stream) the Audio to "another mobile" device "directly" without any in-between components?

Tags: audio, streaming

How to do if I want to play some (any) sounds on one device, and then want another device to hear the same thing at the same time?

And what i also mean is to be able to connect "directly" (via BlueTooth or WiFi) by **not using any in-between Server** or any such components. Or, should i say point-to-point? P2P? (**Lets say without Internet**)

Comment: You may look into [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29566/23379) as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are many apps in the market which you may use to achieve this;

1. [StreamFurious](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.streamfurious.android.free&hl=en)
2. [ServeStream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.servestream&hl=en)

Both app require you to posses access to a ShoutCast server. (which is a server technology to host what you broadcast. [learn more](http://newbietues.enjin.com/forum/m/12404141/viewthread/8531160-so-you-want-to-learn-shoutcast/filter/most-replies)). Services like [listen2myradio](http://www.listen2myradio.com/) provides such services for free. This will allow anyone in the world to listen what you play, realtime!

You may also use bluetooth (with apps like [Bluetooth Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilumnis.btplayerfree&hl=en)) or wifi (with apps like [WiFi Audio Wireless Speaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vnd.wifiaudio&hl=en) or [WiFi Speaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pixelface.android.audio&hl=en)) if you want to stay at a limited area.

Comment: Sorry that i didn't mention clearly. I have updated my question above. Please check again. The point is, i want something WITHOUT in-between server (No Internet)

Comment: You already have the answer for your updated question as well in this answer. :)

Comment: I am looking for "how".