# Can I connect to both a Wifi router and a Wifi Music receiver at the same time?

Tags: wi-fi, streaming, dlna, sony-xperia-z5, airplay

I want to be able to play music from my android phone out of my home sound system, wirelessly. Bluetooth doesn't have a long enough range, so I was going to use Wifi. I also want to be able to connect to the internet on my phone (Spotify etc), at the same time.

I was going to buy this:

[Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neet%C2%AE-Wireless-Receiver-wireless-streaming/dp/B00O0U37HO/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1490795770&sr=8-6&keywords=3.5mm%20wifi%20audio)

But I first want to make sure that I can still connect to the internet (through WiFi router) if I am using this.

I do not want to route my phone.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stream audio from my phone over wifi to a speaker or receiver?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29566/how-can-i-stream-audio-from-my-phone-over-wifi-to-a-speaker-or-receiver)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I think this is different as I'm specifically asking if I can still connect to the internet, while I am streaming the audio.

Comment: I believe you can still connect to the internet at the same time, unless you want to stream local files, therefore it should work pretty fine with spotify. Which internet commection do you want to use ? Is it mobile connection? If you are using home Wi-Fi it should work pretty ok

Comment: Tell us more about this Wi-Fi music receiver. Does it show up as its own Wi-Fi network, or does it connect to your home Wi-Fi network?